# regex to test repeatition of character

Tags: regex

I have a specific requirement to check if all the characters in a string of 8 characters contains repeatition of character '0' 
I was trying to use regular expression 0{8} to validate for all cases to get result as true - 
but above regular expression will validate only  *

```
0
00
000
0000
00000
000000
0000000
00000000 ->*
```

Can anyone suggest if i need to change something in my regular expression to validate all the above inputs ?
Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To detect any number of repetitions of `0`, simply use:

```
0+
```

This matches all your test cases, and of course would match *more* than 8, but if your input string is max 8 chars, it's OK.

Comment: @Bhemian ..That looks great this is what i was looking for. Thanks guys for such a fast response and valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

You should use 0{1,8} to catch all cases you've provided.

Comment: Thanks Alex, but i want to check only 0 ie if a string 0001 comes then it should be invalidated. So this sequence should strictly contains only 0s in repeation and not any other characters etc.

Comment: If you're sure that string won't have newline characters, you can use ^0{0,8}$. This will catch only lines containing 1 to 8 zeros.

Answer (score 2):

`{8}` requires exactly 8 characters. Use a [range](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html):

```
0{1,8}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be easy with the following.

a = '000000000'

b = '000001000'

a.strip('0')  # returns ''

b.strip('0')  # returns '1'

For C++

replace( s.begin(), s.end(), '0', '');

Comment: That would be very good suggestion, provided there's such function in used language (for example, c++ std::string doesn't have it)

Comment: With regexp or simple string manipulation, you can always substitute characters. Substitute '0' with '' and you end up with empty or other characters. For example std::replace( s.begin(), s.end(), 'x', 'y'); // replace all 'x' to 'y'